# React-native JSON-based Form Generation

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to have a react native application call an api for a view json and use the same to create dynamic form elements

Comment: Have you done any search? In fact, stating your efforts is always good to motivate people to answer.

Comment: I am new to react-native and yeah I searched but didn't find any appropriate solution.

Comment: I am not familiar for React. So my main advice, as always, try anything! It is the better to learn. Look at examples that don't fit your needs, but understand them. You will make links and be able to do surely pretty soon. Otherwise, we will be glad to assist you where you block.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [tcomb-form-native](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native) library and the [tcomb-json-schema](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-json-schema) extension to generate native forms from [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) formatted data.